# Failure to compile opencl application with mingw

Tags: opencl

I have used the following

```
mingw32-gcc -std=c99 -Wall -o vec_addition vec_addition.c -I"c:\Program Files\ATI Stream\include" -L"c:\Program Files\ATI Stream\lib\x86" -lOpenCL
```

but I keep getting

> c:\Program Files\ATI Stream\include/CL/cl_platform.h:75:1: error:
>   unknown type name 'int8_t' c:\Program Files\ATI
>   Stream\include/CL/cl_platform.h:76:1: error: unknown type name
>   'uint8_t' c:\Program Files\ATI Stream\include/CL/cl_platform.h:77:1:
>   error: unknown type name 'int16_t' c:\Program Files\ATI
>   Stream\include/CL/cl_platform.h:78:1: error: unknown type name
>   'uint16_t' c:\Program Files\ATI Stream\include/CL/cl_platform.h:79:1:
>   error: unknown type name 'int32_t' c:\Program Files\ATI
>   Stream\include/CL/cl_platform.h:80:1: error: unknown type name
>   'uint32_t' c:\Program Files\ATI Stream\include/CL/cl_platform.h:81:1:
>   error: unknown type name 'int64_t' c:\Program Files\ATI
>   Stream\include/CL/cl_platform.h:82:1: error: unknown type name
>   'uint64_t' c:\Program Files\ATI Stream\include/CL/cl_platform.h:83:1:
>   error: unknown type name 'uint16_t'

I have also used reimp tool to generate libopencl.a from the corresponding lib.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Try adding #include <stdint.h> inside the cl_platform.h header, to check.

Comment: By the way, why are you using ATI Stream? It's deprecated, you should probably be using APP (Accelerated Parallel Processing)

Comment: APP does not support windows xp